# How do I report a bug in te language support preferences?

Tags: language-support

I installed my system using US English, but as my native tongue is Norwegian (Bokmål) I would like to use that on a daily basis on my system. More important, I want to use the Norwegian number formats.

However, in the language support settings, only Norwegian Nynorsk is available. I know there is Norwegian Bokmål support, as my home computer is installed with it. But it's not available from the "install/remove languages" dialog.

Answer (score 2):

try this in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install language-pack-nb language-pack-nb-base language-pack-gnome-nb language-pack-gnome-nb-base
```

this installs four packages. the latter two are only for the case you are using gnome. For KDE e.g. gnome should be replaced by kde.

After that you can hopefully select Bokmal language support.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem itself, but it is still a bug, and should be reported. The question is, which project in Launchpad should receive the report?

Comment: sorry for the late reply. It is not a bug - your preferred language war just not installed. You could as well have used the Synaptic Package Manager to install it.

Comment: Yes, it was not installed, so I clicked the install new languages button, it presented a list of languages that could be installed, included nn_NO, but not nb_NO. Just to be clear, nn_NO wasn't installed either.